# When a media file is selected, and I press SPACE, a media player comes up - which application is responsible for that?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

When a media file is selected, in Nautilus or just on the desktop, and I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, a media player comes up - which application is responsible for that? For example on audio, it displays a record icon along with basic artist info.

It's not coming from eog, not from the default audio player, etc.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME 3.x. Is it a GNOME integrated player, on the newer 3.x series of gnome?? On another machine, it simply fires the default player, mplayer or gnome on audio or video respectively...

Comment: please post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Gnome Sushi.
You can remove it in terminal (ctrl+alt+t) by `sudo apt-get remove gnome-sushi`